# linger.ms and batch.size having no, to little, effect on batching at producers (transactional)

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

We are relatively new to Kafka and are struggling with getting any sort of decent throughput at our services.
Commit latency (replication=3 and acks=all) appears to be severely throttling our throughput, but that's a separate problem.
To try and compensate for this, we're looking to see if we can encourage more batching at the (async) producer. For our requirements, producers need to be transactional with "exactly once semantics" enabled.

However, even when setting linger.ms and batch.size to very high values (e.g. 10 seconds and 1M respectively), we are not seeing any difference.
From what we can tell, only on the very first request, do we see any sort of batching occurring. Subsequent requests however seem to be sent out immediately, regardless of these two settings.
There appears to be a check for any flushes that are in progress at RecordAccumulator which seems to always return true after the first request is sent which we suspect may be the cause here.
Again, we are pretty fresh to Kafka, so our understanding of what these two configuration items do in the context of transactional producers may be incomplete.

Are we correct in expecting that batching would be improved with tuning these two settings when used with transactional producers? Is batching even the correct approach in dealing with our original latency problem here?

We are using Spring-Kafka (2.5.5) / Kafka Client (2.5.1)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How many messages are you trying to send (per second).  How large are they typically?  What is the base latency between your producer and kafka cluster?

Comment: At the moment, we're only observing 1 or 2 msg/s, so any improvement is a positive at this point in time. For comparison, on a dev's workstation we can achieve 200 msg/s per consumer with a single broker (running as a docker container), but for a cluster with 3 brokers, we observe latencies of about 500ms from producer to when the acknowledgement is received. Typically, a message would average around 5kb in size.

Comment: Those are not large messages.  The latency seems really high (should be <10ms if you are colocated with the cluster).  You should be able to produce 10-100k messages per second and consume 100-200k per second.  Could you describe the network setup?

Comment: Could you try running the kafka-producer-performance-perf-test.sh and kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh which are included with your kafka installation.

Comment: `kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic philby-test --num-records 1000 --record-size 5000 --throughput -1 --producer-props acks=all bootstrap.servers=X.X.X.X:XXXX,X.X.X.X:XXXX,X.X.X.X:XXXX
1000 records sent, 818.330606 records/sec (3.90 MB/sec), 454.42 ms avg latency, 947.00 ms max latency, 439 ms 50th, 856 ms 95th, 931 ms 99th, 947 ms 99.9th.
`

Comment: `kafka-consumer-perf-test.sh --broker-list X.X.X.X:XXXX,X.X.X.X:XXXX,X.X.X.X:XXXX --topic philby-test --messages 1000
start.time, end.time, data.consumed.in.MB, MB.sec, data.consumed.in.nMsg, nMsg.sec, rebalance.time.ms, fetch.time.ms, fetch.MB.sec, fetch.nMsg.sec
2020-10-07 08:47:23:001, 2020-10-07 08:47:26:394, 5.9605, 1.7567, 1250, 368.4055, 3045, 348, 17.1278, 3591.9540`

Comment: Our services are deployed to pods on a Kubernetes cluster, but the Kafka brokers themselves each run on their own dedicated VM's in Azure.

Comment: I know nothing about kubes or azure...you might want to take a look at the following for recommendations: https://www.confluent.io/wp-content/uploads/apache-kafka-confluent-enterprise-ref-architecture.pdf

Comment: From what I can tell, we've met all the recommendations outlined in that document. We have a devops team currently trying to diagnose the latency issues anyway, but I think we've digressed somewhat here, my question was mainly finding if there is anything we can do at the producer side (e.g. batching).